# Is 6-gauge wire bendable?

Tags: wiring

Cattle panels are recommended for garden trellises.  I found a reasonable size and price at Tractor Supply -- 8 ft by 4 ft.  I think we will have to cut it in half to make an A-frame, my spouse wants to bend it.  How bendable is 6-gauge wire?

Comment: *Everything* is bendable...

Comment: It also makes a nice (and revertible) "hoop" (inverted U or an arch) if you stake one end to the ground and then walk the other end in and stake it. The panel curves and stands up, **but** is not permanently bent, and can be un-staked and returned to flat/straight. Something to consider rather than the permanently bent A-frame. But I guess that's usually with the 16-foot panels (8 is abnormally short for these panels, IME.) and might not work with one that short.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - That sounds good for a larger operation than mine.  I saw a green bean tunnel in a video yesterday and I bet it was made the way you described.

Answer (score 1):

6 gauge wire can be bent. It may not be too easy to bend though. If you are bending one of those sheets across the short side better than trying to bend it down the long length. Fold it over and step on it to get it started. You may need to put a piece of wood on it and bang it with a sledge hammer to get a fairly tight bend. Nice and solid but maybe overkill.

For my folded garden trellis I used concrete wire but the lighter version. It is 10 gauge and folded easily but still supports itself (and plants) very well. I got tired of those cheap round tomato cages you can buy. I folded some into 24"x 24" squares and cut them to height- they work great.

Comment: Do you need bolt cutters for the trimming?  Will I find the lighter weight remesh at an old-fashioned lumber yard, Home Depot/Lowes, or Tractor Supply?

Comment: yes- small bolt cutters- 12 or 18" long, or a grinder with a metal cutting wheel. You can cut it with a sidecutter pliers (linemans pliers) but takes a lot of hand strength and you will fatigue quickly.  In the trades it is referred to as 6 by 6- #10 welded wire. Call around first. Most lumber yards should have it - possibly Lowes or H/D- not sure about the tractor supply house. It comes in rolls (pretty awkward to use) and it also comes in 8' x 20' sheets (preferable).